# XCode HealthThermometer example compile error

Tags: xcode, core-bluetooth

Hy to all! I'm newbie in coding with Xcode and objective-c. I'm using 8.2 Xcode and i tried to compile the HealthThermometer example from there
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HealthThermometer/Introduction/Intro.html
and it's gives a lots of error:
[image]

What can be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is quite old example code.  It is missing the `#import` required for Core Bluetooth and attempts to link to the older IOBluetooth library.

In order to compile it you will need to change the top of *HealthThermometerClientAppDelegate.h* to read:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
```

You will also need to go into the project settings and remove the IOBluetooth framework and add a reference to `CoreBluetooth.framework`